# ARM Deployment of an Angular Project to Azure Web App

Tags: angular, azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

How do I publish an Angular Project, using only PowerShell and Azure Resource Manager Templates, to my Azure Web App.

I already did the same with an .Net Core application. I published it in Visual Studio, with ARM and PowerShell, but for Angular projects it seems to be not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong, I think we may not be able to do the end-to-end build, publish and deployment activities using ARM templates for Angular project.

But we might be able to accomplish it using PowerShell i.e., with the help of PowerShell script as explained below.

1. Get publish profile details from App service and use it as one of the Input for the script.
2. Run normal npm, ng commands (which are required for typical angular project).
3. Publish build and other required artifacts to kudu or web app for deployment.

   3.1. Get Kudu API athorization header value using Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction cmdlet by giving resource type as Microsoft.Web/sites/config, resource name as YOURWEBAPPNAME/publishingcredentials and other required details.

   3.2. Upload file to web app using Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet by giving URI as Kudu API URL and other required details.

However, I would recommend going with Azure DevOps way or VSCode way (with local Node.js server) which I guess you already might be aware of.

Hope this helps at least up to some extend!! Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently the kudu api is the best option I found. Azure DevOps and Vscode are no option because the deployment should later work as a managed offer in Marketplace.